# A thin arrow within a circle div using css

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a thin arrow (direction towards right) using css.

I have created the circled div but stuck with the arrow

```
<div class="circleBase type2"></div>
```

I have created the fiddle and also attached the reference image

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/c9eyrat6/

[image]

Any hint/suggestion/reference link would do great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an SVG? What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option using a pseudo-element although an image or SVG would probably be preferable.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9eyrat6/7/)

**CSS**

```
.circleBase {
    border-radius: 50%;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc); /* remove if you don't care about IE8 */
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.type2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 3px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

.type2:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:50%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:2px solid white;
    transform:rotate(45deg) ;

}
```

Comment: came out with the approximate same [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/wy02p1zu/2/). This not good practice although its fun to do. I also recommend using SVG ;)

Comment: The solution is brilliant. You saved my day.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Added a div and gave it a white border check if this suits your interest http://jsfiddle.net/c9eyrat6/6/

```
#line{
transform:rotate(-10deg);
width:120px;
height:120px;
border:5px solid white;
}
```